# Ambiguous reference to member 'canShow()'

Tags: swift, xcode, ambiguous, unityads

I've been using the unity ads framework for my app. However, after I converted it to Swift 3, xcode started throwing errors.

I'm trying to call the canShow() method to check if an ad is available:

UnityAds.sharedInstance().canShow()

But I get an error that says "Ambiguous reference to member 'canShow()'"

Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest version of the SDK, available [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/unity-ads-ios/releases).